# How do you run the strings tool properly in Mac OSX Mavericks?

Tags: linux, macos

How do you run the strings tool properly in Mac OSX Mavericks?

I am trying to run it like this per the examples that I found on the web:

```
strings -a UserParser.class
```

But I am getting this error:

> error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strings: fat file: UserParser.class truncated or malformed (offset plus size of cputype (11078144) cpusubtype (17415) extends past the end of the file)

Answer (score 6):

I had success by using just `-` instead of `-a`.

```
strings - UserParser.class
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option: install binutils with homebrew.  Then use its strings command instead.

For me:

```
 brew install binutils
 /usr/local/opt/binutils/bin/strings ...
```