# Can you pipe into the bash strings command?

Tags: bash, macos, pipe

The strings command is a handy tool to extract printable strings from binary input files.
I've used it with files plenty.
But what if I wish to stream to it?

A use case is grepping a stream of data that may be binary for specific strings.
I tried
`data-source | strings -- - | grep needle` to see if the `-` had it treat stdin as a file type, but this doesn't work, `strings` just waits.

Comment: Does `data-source | strings | grep needle` work?

Comment: I'm not following your question -- how is what you're asking different than `strings datasource |grep -o needle`?

Comment: Does `data-source` finish? Or is it something like `tail -f` which keeps waiting for more data?

Comment: Do a `strings <<<12345`. If you get _12345_  in the output, you know that your `strings` reads stdin.

Comment: @rici `tail -f` would be a great example - a stream that doesn't finish.

Comment: @dany: if the stream doesn't finish, you need to pipe through `stdbuf`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the help for `strings`:

```
Usage: strings [option(s)] [file(s)]
 Display printable strings in [file(s)] (stdin by default)
```

You see that stdin is the default behavior if there are no arguments. By adding `-` the behavior seems to change, which is strange, but I was able to reproduce that result too.

So it seems the correct way to do what you want is:

```
data-source | strings | grep needle
```

In a comment, you asked why not `strings datasource |grep -o needle` ?

If you could arrange that command so `datasource` is a stream, it might work, but it's usually easier to arrange that using `|`.

For example, the below are roughly equivalent in zsh. You'd have to figure out a way to do it in your shell of choice if that's not zsh.

```
strings <(tail -f syslog) | grep msec
tail -f syslog | strings | grep msec
```

Comment: Could it be that this depends on the version of `strings` you have? The man-page of _my_ `strings`  (GNU strings (GNU Binutils) 2.37) does **not** say this and is pretty unclear about stdin. Since this program is usually applied to binary input, and pipes are mostly intended to carry text, I would not be surprised if quite some `strings` implementation require explicit file names.

Comment: @user1934428 Not the man page - it's in `strings --help`. I'm on GNU strings 2.26.1.

Comment: @user1934428 pipes can carry any data, e.g.  you can `zcat file.tgz | tar xf -` and it works fine, and is not ASCII text.

Comment: GNU strings doesn't use the convention that a `-` in the filelist stands for `/dev/stdin`. Other strings implementations probably differ. In the GNU implementation, `-` in the file list is equivalent to specifying the option `-a`, except that it only takes effect for following files. (Since `-a` is now the default, that's not often needed; it goes back to the days when `-d` was the default.) Since `-` is recognised in the file list, it's still recognised after `--`. Checking the behaviour of a utility by seeing how it happens to work on your system often produces misleading results.

Comment: @DanLowe : They **can** of course, but it does not mean that any command processing binary data **will** implement it. As I said, `strings` seems to be fine with it and allow for stdin, although the documentaion in **my** man page of _strings_  is a bit unclear about it.

Comment: On a mac trying `echo "the quick brown fox" | strings` and it does nothing until I hit ctrl-c. On an Ubuntu container with binutils installed, I get the "the quick brown fox" output. Ubuntu `GNU strings (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34`. However, `strings --version` on my mac locks until ctrl-c. I am now suspecting that's broken.

Comment: The man page on macos does indeed say `If no  files  are  specified
       standard input is read`. So it should behave the way my original question expected.

Comment: So installing the homebrew version of strings like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943031/how-do-you-run-the-strings-tool-properly-in-mac-osx-mavericks suggests works as I expected.

Comment: @DannyStaple FWIW I cannot reproduce your result on macOS 12.3.1 using /usr/bin/strings - I get "the quick brown fox" back right away, no waiting, no Ctrl-C.

Comment: Interesting - I'm on 11.6.5. I've not done a reinstall as such, only updates since I bought it - 2018 Mac.